# How to to add a percent-based discount?

Tags: 7, commerce

Now during order edit it is possible to apply only a fixed discount. How to to add a percent-based discount?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to install (or perhaps just begin using) [Commerce Discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount).

Discounts are applied either to the individual product line items (product discounts) or the order total (order discounts).